# is there a way to skip class name while define a class member function in c++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, function, class

for example, I declare a class named Dog in the dog.h:

```
class Dog {
public:
    void bark();
private:
    int count;
}
```

Is there any way that I could just write the following code in the dog.cpp:

```
void bark() {
   printf("count: %d", count);
}
```

instead of:

```
void Dog::bark() {
   printf("count: %d", count);
}
```

It will help saving time if I got a ton of class functions which should be defined. (I can just copy-paste the function definition to .h file without the routine to delete class name every time.)

in the objective-c code, I can add a "@implementation ... @end" scope in the .m(its role is like .cpp) file, then I can just write the function like this:

```
in dog.h:
- (void) bark;

in dog.m:
@implementation Dog
- (void) bark {
    printf("count: %d", count);
}
@end
```

So I think maybe there is a similar way in c++.

You see, I can copy the function definition codes in .m file to the .h file, and just need to add a ";" symbol in the line end. I even needn't to declare it in the .h file, if the class function is a private one. So I think objective-c is more convenient than c++ when declaring a class.

Comment: Having `@implementation` ... `@end` means you can't reliably recognise a non-member function without searching back to the top of the file (or perhaps the previous `@end` - if any - or closing of a namespace or whatever else an implementation can't span).  I suppose the same sort of criticism can be made of namespaces though.

Comment: You mention you want to just copy-paste stuff. What exactly are you trying to do? There might be other techniques you can use to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any way that I could just write the following code in the dog.cpp?

No, you cannot do that. You must use the class name when defining member functions outside the class definition.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **9.3 Member functions**
>
> 5 If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class definition, the member function name shall be qualified by its class name using the `::` operator.

Comment: @firestoke , as answered by R Sahu: "no you cannot do that"

Comment: hmm... It really annoy me. I write objective-c codes long time too. I can just  write the member function without class name prefix in the objective-c code by using "@implementation ... @end" in the .m file. so I think maybe there is a similar way in c++...

Comment: It is. People are screwing with you

Comment: @firestoke, The C++ community must not find that to be such a big problem :) Personally, it makes the code more readable with `ClassName::` attached to the implementation. Also, in the long run, the amount of time it takes to add `ClassName::` to the member function implementation fades in comparison to the time it takes to maintain code.

Comment: @firestoke: it's a good thing to try writing code the way the language wants you to.  Imagine someone asking 'is there a way to negate a sentence in French _without_ the annoying `ne ... pas`'?

Answer (score 2):

### Simple pattern

In your cpp file you may use the following pattern:

```
#include "dog.h"

#define _C Dog::

void _C bark () {
...
}

void _C foo () {
...
}

#undef _C
```

The use of the macro `_C` will be the same for any TU.

### More elaborative pattern

Concept: generate code of member implementations straight in the class definition.
The pattern of file structure:

1. the regular header file named `dog.h`
2. the header file with method implementations to be
   included, named "dog.hxx"
3. the cpp file including "dog.h" while the special macro `IMPLEMENT_API` defined

The regular header file `dog.h`:

```
class Dog {
public:
    void bark();
private:
    int count;
#ifdef IMPLEMENT_API
#include "dog.hxx"
#endif
}
```

The `dog.hxx` file:

```
void bark() {
   printf("count: %d", count);
}

void foo() {
   printf("foo: %d", count+1);
}
```

The `dog.cpp` file:

```
#define IMPLEMENT_API
#include "dog.h"
```

In a more complex case, one TU may be used for several instances of the second pattern like in the `animals.cpp` file below.
The `animals.cpp` file:

```
#define IMPLEMENT_API
#include "cat.h"
#include "dog.h"
```

Another class `cat` is defined as `dog` using similar statements with the `IMPLEMENT_API` macro.
In another file including `dog.h` or `cat.h`, only declarations will be generated because the `IMPLEMENT_API` macro must be defined only in a TU like `dog.cpp` or `animals.cpp`.

Pros: `dog.hxx` or `cat.hxx` files use contexts and namespaces of their classes allowing to omit the fully qualified name of a class for each member definition.

Caution: if a compiler does not allow to have a member declaration and a member definition at the same time, member declarations should be wrapped with the pattern `#ifdef IMPLEMENT_API <member definitions> #else <member declarations> #endif`.

Comment: it's better. I can copy the code into other files and using it, and just need to  modify the _C definition to different class name. but I still need to delete "_C" in the .h when I copy it. I am a really lazy developer lol. (I am tired wasting my time in the duplicated unnecessary routines.)

Comment: @firestoke `I still need to delete "_C" in the .h when I copy it.` For PCRE-compatible editors the following may be usefull: `s/@implementation (\w+)/#define _C $1::/g`

Comment: @firestoke `I still need to delete "_C" in the .h when I copy it.` With the second pattern you don't :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for being late.  I don't get around much. ;)

You don't need a .cpp file to define your function.  You can do it in the class definition.  In fact, you must do this if you want it in-lined.

Most people seem to have a .cpp fetish.  ;)  I put almost all my function in the class definition.  Most of my classes don't have a .cpp file, but sometimes they are necessary.

voila!  No Dog:: and no .cpp file either.`enter code here`class Dog {

```
public:
    void bark() {
    printf("count: %d", count);
    }
private:
    int count;
}
```

Comment: In fact, this is fetishism (your words). Once you get say more then 10 functions intermixed with data, and provide definition for all the function, then god helps you. What messy is the style defining it one place. In a header file, I want to know a class interface, not implemenation. That is what .cpp is for, If I want to look at a huge class, I do not expect definition at all, since that is not suppose to be there

Answer (score -2):

mark the function as `friend` in a `class`

```
class Dog {
friend void bark (Dog &); /// mark as friend

private:
int count = 22;
};
```

with this you can access some `private` members in a `class Dog`

```
void bark (Dog &d1)
{
std::cout << d1.count << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Looks like. It does do what the OP wants, sort of. Takes a bunch of extra keystrokes, though.

Comment: It certainly does not do what OP asks. The question is about *member* functions.

Comment: @juanchopanza You are missing the humour of it. OP doesn't want to have to type `dog::`. This solution requires OP to type `friend`, `Dog &` twice, a variable name, and then prefix all member accesses with that variable name. Regardless of whether it's good C++ or not, this is going to be much more inconvenient.

Comment: @user4581301 Hilarious! I almost fell off my chair laughing.

Comment: I got it. What if he coded a dll, injected it into the IDE, detoured the function that gets called when the "compile button" is pressed, checked all the files in the project, put dog:: or whatever class name in front of all functions etc and called the original function which would compile the code, that would save him some time in the future! Told you i got it